# Need advice on comparing the performance of 2 equivalent linq to sql queries

Tags: linq-to-sql, performance

I am working on tool to optimize linq to sql queries. Basically it intercepts the linq execution pipeline and makes some optimizations like for example removing a redundant join from a query. Of course, there is an overhead in the execution time before the query gets executed in the dbms, but then, the query should be processed faster. I don't want to use a sql profiler because I know that the generated query will be perform better in the dbms than the original one, I am looking for a correct way of measuring the global time between the creation of the query in linq and the end of its execution. Currently, I am using the Stopwatch class and my code looks something like this:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
const int amount = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
   ExecuteNonOptimizedQuery();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.Writeline("Executing the query {2} times took: {0}ms. On average, each query took: {1}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / amount, amount);
```

Basically the ExecutenNonOptimizedQuery() method creates a new DataContext, creates a query and then iterates over the results.

I did this for both versions of the query, the normal one and the optimized one. I took the idea from [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2008/03/07/developing-linq-to-llblgen-pro-part-14.aspx) post from Frans Bouma.

Is there any other approach/considerations I should take?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Run under a profiler. But an instrumented build will impact the performance of the code, possibly distorting the result (with a large part of the total execution time in SQL Server, this is very likely). A sampling profiler might help. (The Visual Studio Team System profiler can do both.)

For an isolated test to compare to approaches using `Stopwatch` is generally the preferred approach. You can remove the time show in SQL Profiler from the stopwatch time to get the time in client code (including your post-processing).